# Dealing with model forms in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I thought it would be easier to start using models form instead of regular forms(giving up on all the easy things modelform provides).
But when I try to do this:

```
>>> m = Model.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> f = ModelForm(instance=m)
>>> f.is_valid()
False
>>> f.save()
AttributeError: 'ModelForm' objects has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

I think django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) is wrong by saying:

> Every form produced by ModelForm also has a save() method.   This
>   method creates and   saves a database object from the  data bound to
>   the form. A subclass of ModelForm can accept  an existing model
>   instance as the keyword argument instance; if this is supplied, save()
>   will update that instance. If it’s not supplied, save() will create a
>   new instance of the  specified model

Cause this is just not working for me.

Am I right that the django documentation is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have forgotten to add "data" into the ModelForm instantiation according to the user's request.POST data.

```
f = ModelForm(data=request.POST, instance=m)
f.is_valid()  # is True if the data is ok.
```

In any case, it would be better to post your relevant code: The model class, the model form class and your view.

EDIT: you **must** add a `data=` parameter (or the first parameter, if you don't name it) to a `ModelForm` initialization, if you want `is_valid()` to work. `is_valid` is here to check the given data against the various validation rules, and only if it's ok, lets you save the `ModelForm`. Initializing a `ModelForm` just with the `instance=` named parameter does not trigger any validation, because there is nothing new to validate.

Comment: You know, using ModelForm(whatever, instance=m) or ModelForm(data=whatever, instance=m) results in the same thing in that case. Still, I can't update only one field, it says every field is required thus making is_valid return False. But this must have something to do with my model.

Comment: Yes, I know. Your code snippet did only include an "instance=" parameter for the ModelForm initialization. Also: Please include more relevant code in your question. And: the Django documentation is definitely not wrong in this paragraph you mentioned.